# error on using jquery UI position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I get an error when I try to use jQuery UI to position an element. 
The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined"
I'm trying to make 2 div's slideDown, one at a time. The second div with class of "child", should flip so it doesn't go outside the 330px wide div wrapper container.

```
<div class="wrapper">       
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="sibling">Sibling Text</div>
    <div class="child">
        <h2>title 1</h2>
        <p>here is some text a</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="sibling">Sibling Text</div>
    <div class="child">
        <h2>title 2</h2>
        <p>here is some text b</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

$('.child').position({
    my:"left top",
    at:"left top",
    of: $(this).closest('.sibling),
    collision:"flip",
    within: $('.wrapper')   
});

$('.sibling').on("click",function(){
$('.child').hide();
$(this).parent().find('.child').slideDown();
});

.wrapper{width:330px}
.parent{
float:left;
width:160px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid #000;
position: relative;
}
.child{
width:250px;
position: absolute;
border:1px solid #000;
background-color:rgba(125,125,125,.8);
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:none;
}
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rick_rick/x2enz2bs/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.child').position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "left top",
    of: $(this).closest('.sibling')[0], //pass element instead of array.
    collision: "flip",
    within: $('.wrapper ')
});
$('.sibling ').on("click", function () {
    $('.child ').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.child ').slideDown();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x2enz2bs/16/

Comment: The  above doesn't work for me. I'm using "position" to keep the ."child" inside the container (.wrapper). When I try your fiddle it just goes outside it. the slideDown works, but there's no flipping.